# $firebasearray.$save is not saving the data to firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have an application where I am trying to watch for changes in a controller variable and saving it to firebase if any change happens i.e. 3-way binding.

service.js

```
     var ref = firebase.database().ref('checklists').orderByChild('checklistName').equalTo('Sample Firebase Sumant');
                var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);

                obj.$loaded().then(function () {
                    var key = Object.keys(obj);
                    var treeRef = firebase.database().ref('checklists/' + key[4] + '/tree');
                    fullTreeCache = $firebaseArray(treeRef);
                    fullTreeCache.$loaded().then(function () {
                        compressedTree = clipChildren(fullTreeCache);
                        console.log(compressedTree);
                        promise.resolve(raw ? fullTreeCache : compressedTree);
                    });
```

controller.js

```
    vm.firebaseData =checklistTreeService.getFullTree();
        $scope.$watch(function () {
return vm.firebaseData;
},function() {
vm.firebaseData.$save($scope,vm.firebaseData);
}, true);
```

$save statement is executing when I change a piece of data without any console errors but it's not getting saved to the firebase realtime database. Please help me out if there is something wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the errors by catching it with the .then syntax. Like this:

```
$scope.yourFunc = function() {
    list.$save(recordOrIndex)
            .then(function(){
                // save successful
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
};
```

I believe you are passing too many arguments to $save() based on the docs. You must pass the "modified" record or the index. If you haven't read the documentation on $firebaseArrays being techincally read-only then you should.

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#saverecordorindex